# displaying two datepicker in angular 2 material

Tags: datepicker, angular-material

why can't I display two matDatepicker in the same page? like putting From date and to Date. everytime that I display this two datepicker it doesn't show up the whole page and It didn't even give me an error.

```
<mat-card>
     All Activities
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput name="from" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="From">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

                </mat-form-field>   

                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput name="to" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="To">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

                </mat-form-field>   
        </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different id's for both. For example: pickerFrom and pickerTo.

     All Activities

```
            </mat-form-field>   

            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerTo" placeholder="To">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #pickerTo></mat-datepicker>

            </mat-form-field>   
    </mat-card>
```

Comment: yeah I figured it out.